# A for loop in simple c++ program in g++ 7.5 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        int year[n + 1];
        year[0] = 1;
        year[1] = 2;
        year[2] = 3;
        year[3] = 4;
        year[4] = 6;
        for (int i = 5; i <= n; i++) {
            year[i] = year[i - 1] + year[i - 3];
        }
        cout << year[n - 1] << endl;
        // for (int temp : year)
        //     cout << temp << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem lies in that for loop.
I did not change the value of n.When I run it with n=2,it outputs not the correct answer but 10.After debugging, I found that when 1 or 2 is entered, the value of n is changed to 6 when the for loop is executed. And when 3 or 4 is entered, the output is normal. At the same time, I also tried other compilers, which did not have this problem, and I also accpted after submitting this question.Is something wrong with my g ++? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code is not valid C++. Variable length arrays (i.e. `int year[n +1]`) for which the size is not known at compile time are not supported. When you use e.g. n = 2, and then write to `year[4]` you're writing to an element that's not even in the array, which is undefined behavior. At that point, anything can happen.

Comment: If `n` is smaller than `4`, then you will write *out of bounds* of the array `year`. Writing out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And as mentioned, [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) like your `year` array aren't technically in standard C++, but a compiler might have added it as a non-portable extension. Please use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You still have to make sure the length of the vector is long enough though.

Comment: You could add `-pedantic-errors` to your compile statement to disable such extensions like VLA

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,I finally know the problem, I need more work